# Show that mod-function is surjective

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

We are to show that the following function is surjective, when n is from the set of integers: $$(4n+6)mod(1729)$$
The codomain are the integers from {0, 1728}

How do I proceed?

In advance, thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't see a function? What's the codomain?

Comment: If you like my answer, you can make it final by accepting it (clicking the green arrow under the voting buttons).

Comment: Please add the tags modular-arithmetic and elementary-number-theory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We see that

$$4n+6\equiv 4k+6\mod{1729}\iff 4(n-k)\equiv 0\mod{1729}$$

since $\gcd(4,1729)=1$, this will only be true if $n\equiv k\mod{1729}$. Thus, among the numbers $\{0,1,2...1728\}$ no numbers will map to the same number mod $1729$, and thus since this is a set a $1729$ elements they must uniquely map to each number mo $1720$ and thus your function is surjective.

EDIT:

In general, the function $an+b\mod{c}$ will be surjective if $\gcd(a,c)=1$, by doing the same construction and examining the set of numbers $\{0,1,2...c-1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If we can solve for any $k; 0\le k < 1729$ and any $m$ that $4n + 6-1729m = k$ we are done.

So we need to solve for $4n = k +1729m -6$ so $n =\frac {k+1729m-6}4 =\frac {k+m-2}4 +432m-1$

If $k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ then we can let $m=2$ and let $n = \frac {k}4+ 863$.

(Verify.  If $k = 4j$ then $4(j +863)+6 = 4j +3458=k +2\cdot 1729 \equiv k\pmod {1729}$.)

If $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ then we can let $m=1$ and let $n = \frac {k-1}4 + 431$

(verify.  If $k = 4j+1$ then $4(j + 431)+6 = 4j +1730=4j+1 =$k$)

If $k\equiv 2 \pmod 4$ then we can let $m=0$ and $n =\frac {k-2}4 -1$.

(verify.  If $k = 4j + 2$ then $4(j-1) + 6 = 4j + 2 = k$.)

If $k \equiv 3\pmod 4$ then we can let $m=-1$ and $n =\frac {k-3}4 -433$.

(verify.  If $k = 4j +3$ then $4(j-433)+6 = 4j -1726= 4j + 3-1729=k-1729\equiv k\pmod{1729}$.)

======

If you know number theory (the above answer assumes you don't) then you know as $4$ and $1729$ are relatively prime the for ever $k$ there is a $k'$ so that $4k'\equiv k\pmod {1729}$, and therefor there is a $n$ so that $4n\equiv k-6\pmod {1729}$ for every $k$.

And you don't have to say any more than that.

If you actually want to *solve* $4n + 6\equiv k \pmod{1729}$ (which you *DON'T* have to do-- it's enough to know a solution always exist-- which the above paragraph amply argues), you first figure what is the $4^{-1}$ so that $4 \times 4^{-1}\equiv 1\pmod {1729}$.

Now $4*432=1728 \equiv -1\pmod{1729}$

So $4*(-432) \equiv 4*1297 \equiv 1 \pmod{1729}$.

So to solve $4n + 6 \equiv k \pmod{1729}$

$4n \equiv k-6\pmod{1729}$

$-(432)*4n  \equiv 6*432 - 432k\pmod{1729}$

$-1728n \equiv 2592-432k\pmod{1729}$

$n \equiv 863 -432k\pmod {1729}$.

will solve any $4n + 6\equiv k\pmod {1729}$.

(verify:  $4(863-432k) + 6\equiv$

$3458 - 1728k \equiv 2*1729+k - 1729k \equiv$

$k\pmod {1729}$.
$4\times